# Dynamics 365 Developer Toolkit for VS 2019

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax, dynamics-nav

I am new to Dynamics 365 and have just started learning it.
I am looking for a developer toolkit for Dynamics 365 which is supported for VS 2019.

The below MS toolkit supports VS 2015 and not the higher versions.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DynamicsCRMPG.MicrosoftDynamicsCRMDeveloperToolkit&ssr=false#overview

While I could find some hacks to get it working for VS 2019 , I could not get it installed.

I tried following the steps mentioned here:(https://crmfortress.com/2017/06/02/dynamics-365-developer-toolkit-extensions-for-vs2017/)
but no luck.

**extension.vsixmanifest file contents:**
 
    -->

I am getting this error:

This VSIX package is invalid because it does not contain the file extension.vsixmanifest at the root. The VSIX file may be corrupted.

(1) Can someone please suggest how do I get this working for VS 2019 ?

(2) If #(1) is not possible, can you please suggest a good alternative to the Microsoft Dynamics Developer toolkit which would work for VS 2019 ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following article contains the instructions:
[How to upgrade extensions to support Visual Studio 2019](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/how-to-upgrade-extensions-to-support-visual-studio-2019/).

In short, you have downloaded the right software, but the
extension.vsixmanifest file needs to be adapted to VS2019:

> Here’s a version that support every major and minor versions of Visual
>   Studio 14.0 (2015) and 15.0 (2017) all the way up to but not including
>   version 16.0.
>
> ```
> <Installation InstalledByMsi="false"> 
>    <InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro" Version="[14.0,16.0)" /> 
> </Installation>
> ```
>
> Simply change the upper bound of the version range from 16.0 to 17.0,
>   like so:
>
> ```
> <Installation InstalledByMsi="false">
>     <InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro" Version="[14.0,17.0)" />
>     </Installation>
> <Prerequisite>
> ```
>
> Next, update the version ranges in the `<Prerequisite>` elements.
>   Here’s what it looked like before:
>
> ```
> <Prerequisites> 
>    <Prerequisite Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor" Version="[15.0,16.0)" DisplayName="Visual Studio core editor" /> 
> </Prerequisites>
> ```
>
> We must update the version ranges to have the same upper bound as
>   before, but in this case we can make the upper bound open ended, like
>   so:
>
> ```
> <Prerequisites> 
>    <Prerequisite Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor" Version="[15.0,)" DisplayName="Visual Studio core editor" /> 
> </Prerequisites>
> ```
>
> This means that the Prerequisite needs version 15.0 or newer.
>
> If you have a dependency on Microsoft.VisualStudio.MPF then delete it.
>   This dependency is a legacy one that hasn’t been needed since before
>   Visual Studio 2010. It looks something like this:
>
> ```
> <Dependencies>
>    <Dependency Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.MPF.14.0" DisplayName="Visual Studio MPF" d:Source="Installed" Version="[14.0]" />
> </Dependencies>
> ```

Comment: Hi @Harrymc , Thanks for your reply but I have already tried this approach. When I follow these steps, I am getting this error:

This VSIX package is invalid because it does not contain the file extension.vsixmanifest at the root. The VSIX file may be corrupted. Any more suggestions ?

Comment: The above changes worked apparently for many users. If you don't have a `extension.vsixmanifest` file, then your installation is corrupted. Try downloading it again.

Comment: The package does have extension.vsixmanifest file with VS version updated to 16 (to support VS 2019).

Comment: extension.vsixmanifest file contents: <Installation>
    <!--<InstallationTarget Version="[11.0,12.0)" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro" TargetPlatformVersion="4.0" />-->
    <InstallationTarget Version="[11.0,16.0]" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Premium" />
    <InstallationTarget Version="[11.0,16.0]" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro" />
    <InstallationTarget Version="[11.0,16.0]" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Ultimate" />
    <InstallationTarget Version="[11.0,16.0]" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise" />
  </Installation>

Comment: This is what everyone recommends. Have you looked into the VSIXInstall log (perhaps file VSIX.log)?

Comment: Initializing Install...
10/25/2019 3:04:25 PM - Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.MissingPackagePartException: This VSIX package is invalid because it does not contain the file extension.vsixmanifest at the root. The VSIX file may be corrupted.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.InstallableExtensionImpl.ReadVSIXManifestFromPackage(Stream stream, CultureInfo preferredCulture)

Comment: This is the VSIX Install log (pls see my previous comment) @harrymc

Comment: The error message might be misleading. I have downloaded and unpacked `Microsoft.CrmDeveloperTools.vsix` and taken a look. I think the above advice in my answer is incorrect or out of date. See [this blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/how-to-upgrade-extensions-to-support-visual-studio-2019/) that looks to me much better. I also don't like the `<Dependencies>` section which should maybe be totally replaced by `<Prerequisite>` as in this link.

Comment: Hi @Harrymc,  this blog worked for me. Thank you so much for your time and suggestions on this. I had to setup few paths also in VS 2019.

Comment: I have replaced the advice in my answer with the blog.

Comment: Hi @harrymc, marked your answer as accepted. I really appreciate your help !